# Not able to update records using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, update

In a trigger I am trying to update values of child records which are pulled from a perent record. I can see the updated data in the debug statements but the actual records are not getting updated.

```
   trigger PaymetUpdater on Corpus_Donation__c (after update) 
 {
    Double totalAmountRecieved;
    Id corpousDonationId;
    List<Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c> futurePlans;
    if(trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if(trigger.isUpdate)
        {
           for(Corpus_Donation__c cd:trigger.new)
           {
                totalAmountRecieved=cd.Total_Amount_Paid__c;
                corpousDonationId=cd.Id;

           }
        System.debug('Total amount recieved is : '+totalAmountRecieved);
        futurePlans=[select id,Amount_Paid__c,Plan_Amount__c,Staus__c from Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c where Corpus_Donation__c=:corpousDonationId];
        System.debug('future plans size :'+futurePlans.size());

        for(Integer i=0;i<futurePlans.size();i++)
        {
            Decimal planAmount=futurePlans.get(i).Plan_Amount__c;
            String status=futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c;
            if(totalAmountRecieved>planAmount)
            {
                if(i>0)
                {
                    i=i-1; 
                }

                futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c=planAmount;
                futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c='Completed';
                totalAmountRecieved=totalAmountRecieved-planAmount;
                i=i+1;
            }
            if(totalAmountRecieved==planAmount)
            {

                futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c=planAmount;
                futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c='Completed';
                break;
            }
            if(totalAmountRecieved<planAmount)
            {

                futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c=totalAmountRecieved;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.debug('Future plans final list :'+futurePlans);
        update futurePlans;
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many things to comment on that piece of code. The first one is that it doesn't make sense, and the second is that it has many redundant sentences. In any case, I'll comment the major flaws so you can continue debugging:

First, the algorithm is wrong. **You are comparing every `Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c` of every `Corpus_Donation__c` ONLY to the last donation which entered the trigger.** For more details, check the comments in the code which I refactored for you below.

Second, if you are to update the future plans with the information of current ones with whatever business logic your company needs, then **you might need to map records in memory in order to work with them.** In other words, when you query the `Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c`, create a `Map<Id, List<Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c>>` which will behold the relationships  (I assume it's that one which you need, but I'm not 100% sure since you didn't specify. Maybe you just need a 1 - 1 map.) . That way you can afterwards iterate them properly and access the properties.

Lastly, regarding code redundancy, you can omit multiple `if` clausules. For example, **if the trigger is only on `after update`, you're guaranteed that it will not trigger on insert, or delete, nor on before.** Therefore, you don't need the checks.

Here is the refactored code with some comments. I recommend you go through it, rethink the algorithm and if you have more questions down the road on the data structures needed, the actual algorithm or simply apex, then create a new question :)

```
trigger PaymetUpdater on Corpus_Donation__c (after update) 
{
    Double totalAmountRecieved;
    Id corpousDonationId;
    List<Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c> futurePlans;

    for(Corpus_Donation__c donation : Trigger.new)
    {
        totalAmountRecieved = donation.Total_Amount_Paid__c; // BUG: You're not mapping this so with every iteration, the value gets overriden.
        corpousDonationId = donation.Id;
    }

    System.debug('Total amount recieved is : ' + totalAmountRecieved); // This prints the value of the last donation which entered the trigger.

    // I assume you would be interested in mapping these future plans to the current donations?
    futurePlans = [SELECT Id, Amount_Paid__c, Plan_Amount__c, Staus__c FROM Corpus_Donation_Future_Plan__c WHERE Corpus_Donation__c = :corpousDonationId];
    System.debug('future plans size :' + futurePlans.size());

    for(Integer i = 0; i < futurePlans.size(); i++)
    {
        Decimal planAmount = futurePlans.get(i).Plan_Amount__c;
        String status = futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c;

        // BUG: You are comparing every future plan of EVERY Corpus donation to the same amount, which is the amount of the last donation of the trigger.
        if(totalAmountRecieved > planAmount)
        {
            if(i > 0)
            {
                i=i-1; 
            }

            futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c = planAmount;
            futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c = 'Completed';
            totalAmountRecieved = totalAmountRecieved - planAmount;
            i=i+1;
        }

        if(totalAmountRecieved == planAmount)
        {
            futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c=planAmount;
            futurePlans.get(i).Staus__c='Completed';
            break;
        }

        if(totalAmountRecieved < planAmount)
        {
            futurePlans.get(i).Amount_Paid__c = totalAmountRecieved;
            break;
        }

    }

    System.debug('Future plans final list :' + futurePlans);
    update futurePlans;
}
```